# How to enhance Box.com API requests limit

Tags: box-api

As wrote here http://blog.programmableweb.com/2013/01/11/opening-up-the-box-api/ box.com limits number of requests to its API on per developer (or client in terms of OAuth RFC) basis.
"The current rate limit is 50,000 requests per developer in a 24 hour rolling window."
Can some1 guide me is there a way to enhance this limt? Cant find anything about it on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rate limit is actually much more granular (different calls are limited differently), and quite a bit higher than what you quote for many types of API calls.  Box uses a leaky-bucket implementation to protect it's servers, but each user is allowed to go pretty hard against the API for short bursts.  If you are a paying customer, Box will tell you what your rate limit is, but we do not make the numbers public.

If you are looking to get a temporarily higher rate limit, you can submit a support request.

Comment: Maybe i didnt understand right. For example we have mobile and desktop application that allow user to store some docs on clouds including box. com. Lets say we have 50000 users that every day get files list, get some file from box, edit it and stores back.
1. So getting fileslist, get file and store file counts as differnt calls?
2. As soon as we have 50001 user he will receive error at these calls because it will be over limits?

Comment: Getting the filelist counts as 1 call.   Downloading the file counts as another api call.   Uploading a new version counts as a 3rd API call.  Each user logged into Box via your app gets their own rate limit.  So the 500th user, as well as the 50001st user all get no errors, as long as they are all logged into Box.   If you are all storing multiple users stuff in a single account, then whoever makes the nth call every minute gets rate limited.  That's because it would all look like 1 user to us.  Remember each OAuth session is for a different user, granting access to their storage.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the answer. We are experiencing some throttling issues lately. Just to be clear, so the API rate limit is bounded to per connected Box user? Say there are 10 users using my app. And for each of them, they can make 50k requests per day and essentially makes my app capable of making 500k requests in total? Then what exactly is this enterprise pricing for? http://info.box.com/content-api

Comment: @RobertKang, Yes, API rate limit is per-user.  More users on your app means more requests that your app is allowed to make, in total. Enterprise users and free users can user your app.  Enterprise users will be able to upload larger files, get more quota to store files (unlimited), and will be rate-limited at higher rates than Free users.  If you have users getting rate-limited, then you may be making more API calls than you need to (polling too frequently?), or you have very active users.