# Do as-user requests count for that user's rate limit?

Tags: box-api, box

In [How to enhance Box.com API requests limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512412/how-to-enhance-box-com-api-requests-limit), it's explained that each user gets its own rate limit. Does this apply only when the request is sent from the user itself, or also when an admin sends the request [as the user](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#as-user-1)? Eg, if my admin account sends 25000 requests as user A, and 25001 requests as user B, will it be rate limited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of rate limiting to consider:

1. *Requests per second*: this is applied on a per user (account) basis. If you are making *n* API calls per second on behalf of user A, you can concurrently make *n* calls per second on behalf of user B without being rate-limited. These limits are not published but [you can learn more about them if you're a paying customer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512412/how-to-enhance-box-com-api-requests-limit)
2. *Total requests per day*: The developer terms of service state that this is "currently set at a limit of 50,000 requests, collectively, for all of Developer's Applications, applied in a rolling 24-hour window." Per the linked question above I don't think the 50K ceiling is enforced. But it's in the ToS so it *could* be enforced at any time.

Comment: How does this relate to "API actions", which are set at 25 000, 50 000 or 100 000 per **month** on, for instance, https://www.box.com/en_GB/pricing/ ?

Comment: I think those monthly limits would apply per user, but you should confirm with Box sales.